# Can the country of departure be different from the country in which you applied your visa in?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

I am currently a UK resident but I am originally from Kuwait. I’ve decided to apply from Kuwait with plans to enter Schengen area from the UK. Would that be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ordinarily resident in the UK you might not be able to apply in Kuwait.

However, once you have a valid visa, you may enter from wherever you wish.

There are many reasons why you might wish to do that - a lack of direct flights, for example, or a multi-stop itinerary. It's commonplace and won't raise an eyebrow anywhere.

<sup>(Thanks to @MarkJohnson for his input)</sup>

Comment: Schengen Visa should be **applied** for from an applicants main place of residence, so the answer to this is no. With a valid visa, they may enter/exit from/to anywhere they chose.

Comment: @mark Do you have a reference for the first part of your comment? Various sites I've checked (including [europa.eu](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/how_to_apply_en)) make no reference to country of residence.

Comment: [European Commission, Schengen visa - Where and how to apply](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/how_to_apply_en) **As a general rule, you must apply for a visa at the Consulate with territorial competence for the country in which you legally reside.**

Comment: Oops! Missed that on the page I referenced, @mark. Thanks.

Comment: This may be correct in theory, but in practice a Kuwaiti citizen applying at the embassy in Kuwait is unlikely to be questioned about their residence status there.

Comment: A citizen is never going to be deemed to be non resident in their own country when applying for a foreign visa. Only foreigners to the country of application would be required to prove their residence status.